# Automapper complex mapping

Tags: mapping, automapper

How can I map the following:

```cs
public abstract class PersonBase
{
   public Address Address { get; set; }         
}

public class Address
{
  public string AddressHome { get; set; }
  public int PostalNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEditVM : PersonBase
{ 
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

public PersonEntity
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string AddressHome { get; set; }
  public int PostalNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to map `PersonEntity` to `PersonEditVM`.

EDIT: **Solved after a cup of coffee but it would be nice if it's a cleaner solution?.**

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonEntity, PersonEditVM >()                
                .ForMember(d=>d.Address, s=>s.MapFrom(p=> new Address{
                    AddressHome = p.AddressHome,
                    PostalNumber = p.PostalNumber
                    }));
```

Comment: solved, but im interested if there is a cleaner solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it, which would split your `Adress` (which is correctly spelled `Address` by the way) mapping into another `CreateMap` call:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonEntity, PersonEditVM>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Adress, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

Mapper.CreateMap<PersonEntity, Adress>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AdressHome, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AdressHome))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PostalNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PostalNumber));
```

Comment: @plurby: What do you mean 'it's still the same'? What would a cleaner solution look like?

Comment: I didn't mean it's not clean, just that i was hoping for a cleaner solution if possible where i don't need to specify every property.

Comment: @plurby: I see, I don't think you can get it done in one line without a custom resolver, but hopefully someone will come along and prove me wrong `:)`. You could remove the `ForMember` calls for the mapping to `Adress`